# How to make Sass variables for an entire CSS property?

Tags: css, sass

I would like to have a Sass variable like this:

```
$flex: 'display: flex';
```

to then be used in my styling like this:

```
.button {
    $flex;
}
```

The way I am showing does not work. Is this possible with SCSS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it another way.

```
%flex { 
  display: flex;
}

.button {
  @extend %flex;
}
```